# selenium - how to program using a select dropdown menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, selenium, keypress

I want to simulate the user clicking on a text field, using the dropdown and selecting an item.

I can get them on the field and the dropdown working with:

```
click    //input[@id='select_students']
keyPress //input[@id='select_student']   \40
```

but I can't seem to get 'picking' an item in the dropdown.

I've tried using `keyPress` with `Keys.ENTER` as the value but I get forced to put in a Target (selenium IDE in firefox this is) and I don't know what to use as the target.

I could use something that press Enter regardless regardless of target if it's available.

Answer (score 0):

Below logic might be useful for you.

```
click  css=select[id="select_students"]
select css=select[id="select_students"]   label=student10
click  css=option[value="student10"]
```

Comment: This method doesn't cause `change` events to fire in IE drivers.  Do you know a method which does?